# nextjs components library

Tags: module, next.js, styled-components

I'm not sure if this is the right place, I've created a node_modules where I have storybook and all my components, I want to use them in my next project but it doesn't work very well, I can see the component but on the page load is without any style and after half second the style is applied. Moving the components inside nextjs works fine:

```
// import Nav from '../components/Nav'; => works
// import Footer from '../components/Footer'; => works
import { Nav, Footer } from 'ui-components'; => not working
```

I'm importing the library with this:

```
module.exports = withTM({
  transpileModules: ['ui-components'],
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'styled-components': path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules/styled-components')
    };
    return config;
  },
});
```

and this is the babelrc on the ui-component module:

```
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "modules": false
    }
  ],
  "@babel/preset-react"
]
```

any suggestions?